# Navigating through stack in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, cpu-registers

Ok , so I have to write an assembly function (i32 x86 little endian) to which i pass 1 unsigned number. The function has to swap first appearance of min and max digit in that number.

My idea was to push all the digits to a stack and then find min and max, save their addresses in registers and swap them.

I have a problem because i can't do the following `cmp [eax],[esp+4*ecx]`. I have 2 questions is there any way to compare values of 2 addresses and can i somehow place esp to eax : `mov eax,esp` (i want the pointer not the value).

Note: I'm a bit new to this assembly stuff.

Comment: I don't really follow your logic, not sure what you need a stack for. Also not sure what format you use. Anyway, to do that compare load one of the values into a register. As for `mov eax,esp` that's valid and does what you said (transfers the stack pointer into `eax`)

Comment: @Jester if i do `mov eax,esp` and then for example `add esi,[eax]` will this add the value from esp(eax) to esi ? 
Edit:And could you please tell me whats the easiest way to navigate from esp to ebp?

Comment: Yes, `add esi, [eax]` would add the topmost item from the stack. I don't understand your second question.

Comment: If i have 10 bytes between ebp and esp  on a stack how do i access them starting from esp ?

Comment: Use an index register which runs from 0 to 9?

Comment: Post more code to understando what you do and how you are doing it (your full program would be great).

Comment: C compilers often use prologue code like: `push ebp mov ebp,esp`. This stores old ebp value in stack, and loads current `esp` into `ebp`: so you can address values on stack trough `ebp` like: `[ebp]` contains previous ebp value, `[ebp+4]` has return address of call, `[ebp+8..]` is stack space of caller (usually parameters are stored right above ret address), and `[ebp-1 to rest_of_available_stack]` is your local function stack space, where C puts stack variables. If you use the same prologue, you can use `[ebp-4*i]` (`i = 0 ... n`) as temporary buffer. `mov esp,ebp pop ebp ret` will return.

Comment: But you are free to do anything you wish - although you probably don't want to corrupt the stack, and you do want to return to the caller, so anything at `[esp]` and above is no-change zone for your code. How do you use memory area under esp is up to you, also by which register you will address it (`esp` itself is not very handy, as instructions working with it are limited, `ebp` is usually easiest to use with stack memory).